# Content Provider passing file in android not work proberly

Tags: android

I need to open pdf documents in my android application..
I used the intent to start foxit pdf reader..
if I pass file from sd card directly, foxit reader run without problems.
But My pdf files located in private folder in my app, so I use ContentProvider to pass the file, by overriding openFile(Uri uri,int mode) method in my ContentProvider.
here I pass ParcelFileDescriptor.
the foxit reader run and my document appear on reader view, but the proble that all tools in foxit reader is disabled, this problem appears just when using ContentProvider.
I tried to change file mode to READ_WRITE and others, but the problem still appears.
what is the solution of this problem, please.
thank you very much.

here is my openFile method:

```
@Override
public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(Uri uri, String mode) {
    try{            

        File f=new File(uri.getPath());
        if (f.exists()) {
            ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = ParcelFileDescriptor.open(f, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY);
            return pfd;
        }
    }catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "File not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;        
}
```

Comment: You may wish to consider using `FileProvider` rather than writing your own: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html

Comment: thanks.. I tried to use FileProvider but I have the same problem.

Comment: Then contact Foxit and ask them what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say what's wrong, since a 3rd party tool is involved. Also, you don't say what type of URI you're passing to openFile. If you're passing a file:// URI, your approach probably won't work. You'll need to clarify a bit, but my hunch is that foxit pdf reader isn't able to handle files in your internal storage.